# "no matching index found" pouchdb using $or

Tags: pouchdb

Is there a better way to write this so that the index is recognized?

```
localDB.createIndex({
        index: {
            fields: ['choirSpecialGroupId','openerGroupId','singingSpecialId','playingOffertoryId']
        }
        }).then(function (result) {
            console.log(result);
            localDB.find({
                selector: {$or: [
                            {
                                'choirSpecialGroupId': {$eq: musicGroupId}
                            },
                            {
                                'openerGroupId': {$eq: musicGroupId}
                            },
                            {
                                'singingSpecialId': {$eq: musicGroupId}
                            },
                            {
                                'playingOffertoryId': {$eq: musicGroupId}
                            }
                            ]
                        }
            }).then(function(result){
                console.log(result);
```

The result from createIndex shows that the index exists.  However, the result from .find gives the warning:

> "no matching index found, create an index to optimize query time."

What am I doing wrong?  Thank you in advance.